# Ionic 3 How to close modal with Tabs and pass data to parent

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Is this possible to create modal with contains Tabs and when select item pass data to parent view?

I known that Tabs have own, separate history stack so if is not possible what is best way to implement that like Tabs-looking way?

Creating modal with tabs from parent view:

```
selectContractor() {        
    let contractorsModal = this.modalCtrl.create('VisitAddTabsPage', {routeId: this.routeId});
    contractorsModal.present();
    contractorsModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

**VisitAddTabsPage.ts**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'page-visit-add-tabs',
 templateUrl: 'visit-add-tabs.html'
})
@IonicPage()
export class VisitAddTabsPage {

ownContractorsRoot = 'OwnContractorsPage'
closestContractorsRoot = 'ClosestContractorsPage'
allContractorsRoot = 'AllContractorsPage'

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams,
            public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
}
}
```

**visit-add-tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" selectedIndex="1">
<ion-tab [root]="ownContractorsRoot" tabTitle="Moi" tabUrlPath="own" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="closestContractorsRoot" tabTitle="W pobliżu" tabUrlPath="closest" tabIcon="locate"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="allContractorsRoot" tabTitle="Wszyscy" tabUrlPath="all" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Closest-contractors tab (**closest-contractors.ts**)

```
    handleSelectedContractor(data) {
    console.log(this.navCtrl);
    console.log(this.appCtrl.getRootNav());
    //this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data); <-- HOW TO DISMISS MODAL (and TABS) AND PASS DATA
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can do that using [Events](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).**

You can always emit an event, carrying any data you want, from any DOM element to any of it's parent dom elements.

So from the **child page** do something like this:

```js
import { EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';


@Component({ 
  ...
})
export class ChildPage {
  @Output() tabGotClosed = new EventEmitter();

  let data: any;

  ...

  notifyPickupConfirmed() {
    this.tabGotClosed.emit(data);
  }
}
```

Then in the **parent page**'s template you can just catch the event like you would with any other:

```html
<ion-content (tabGotClosed)="onTabGotClosed($event)">
```

In this way, the page that opened the modal can finally have the data available to it after the modal closes by just looking into the data carried by the event `event.detail.tabGotClosed`.

Comment: I tried to use events but i dont know where to handle it.
I have the button that oppening the modal with Tabs
`<button ion-button="" color="primary" block large (click)="selectContractor()">Select contractor  </button>`

then i have Tabs layout
`<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" selectedIndex="1">
    <ion-tab [root]="ownContractorsRoot" tabTitle="Moi" tabUrlPath="own" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>
...
</ion-tabs>`
and then tab layout.

So i dont know where to catch event.

Comment: It doesn't matter really, as long as the modal is a child element it will work. Just inspect your app with the modal open and any element that is parent of the modal, you can catch the event there. Which is why I showed you doing it in the `ion-content`. The events just bubble up the DOM towards the root.